# Contour of Likelihood (2 parameters)

Tags: r

I have to estimate the likelihood between two parameters fe (y-axis) and fc (x-axis) and draw the contour plot. The model is sinusoidal ,

[image]

As you can there are there are three free parameters, fc , fe and t0.  Where y and x are in our datasets.

```
months=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
frac=c(0.3690323, 0.3230706, 0.3095238, 0.2549206, 0.1850998, 0.05614035, 0.04584041, 0.06513057, 0.208254, 
       0.3004608, 0.344127, 0.3136713)
error= c(0.04628507 ,0.05000108, 0.02780694, 0.03403128, 0.0253194, 0.008280586, 0.01247297, 0.009350916, 0.02627754, 
         0.03296408,0.03841221, 0.03688875)


fc <- fe <- seq(0.0025, 1, 0.005)
chisq.table <- matrix(NA, 200, 200)


fun.to.minimize <- function(params,x,y,var) {
    fc <- params[1]
    fe <- params[2]
    t0 <- params[3]
    output <- sum(((y-fc-fe * sin(2* pi *(x- t0)/12))/var)^2)
    return(output)
}


fun.to.minimize.t0 <- function(params,x,y,var,fc,fe) {
    t0 <- params[1]
    output <- sum(((y-fc-fe * sin(2* pi *(x- t0)/12))/var)^2)
    return(output)
}





for (i in 1:200){
    for (j in 1:200){

        xmin <- optimize(fun.to.minimize.t0 , c(0, 1), fc = fc[i] , fe = fe[j] , x=months, y=frac, var=error)

        chisq2.matrix <- optim(c(fc[i],fe[j],xmin$objective), fun.to.minimize, x=months, y=frac, var= error)
        chisq.table[i, j] <- chisq2.matrix$value

    }
}


contour(x =fc,y = fe,
        z= chisq.table)
```

I got this plot.

[image]

I was hoping to get points in all regions and also how can I add Confidence Interval in this plot?

Comment: Is the question about the code needed to make the plot, or about the statistics? If it's about stats rather than code, this should be on [stats.se] instead. I can't run your code, because we don't have your data frac.month. Also, confidence interval of what?

Comment: @camille I have made changes in the code and added the data. The question is related to coding.